# Difference between panel fieldset and container in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

i am  new to Extjs technology.I running over a small confusion or may be just not able to visualize it. What is the difference between  panel fieldset and container in Extjs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not show any attempt to research the question on your part. SO is the place to ask specific questions, not request someone put available documentation in layman's terms.

Comment: See also [Container vs Panel in Extjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857918/container-vs-panel-in-extjs)

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to the docs, it's explained very well there:

[**Ext.container.Container**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.container.Container.html)

> Base class for any Ext.Component that may contain other Components. Containers handle the basic behavior of containing items, namely adding, inserting and removing items.

[**Ext.panel.Panel**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html)

> Panel is a container that has specific functionality and structural components that make it the perfect building block for application-oriented user interfaces.

[**Ext.form.FieldSet**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.form.FieldSet.html)

> A container for grouping sets of fields, rendered as a HTML fieldset element. The title config will be rendered as the fieldset's legend.

(just to quote the first paragraphs of each component, there's a lot more useful information contained)

Answer (score 0):

The way the HTML the generated is different than just a different container. It also gives you some convenience default settings etc.I'd say it would be good if you have to group fields rather than arbitrary components.
To quote ExtJS documentation:

"A container for grouping sets of fields, rendered as a HTML fieldset element. The title config will be rendered as the fieldset's legend.

While FieldSets commonly contain simple groups of fields, they are general Containers and may therefore contain any type of components in their items, including other nested containers. The default layout for the FieldSet's items is 'anchor', but it can be configured to use any other layout type.

FieldSets may also be collapsed if configured to do so; this can be done in two ways:

Set the collapsible config to true; this will result in a collapse button being rendered next to the legend title, or:
Set the checkboxToggle config to true; this is similar to using collapsible but renders a checkbox in place of the toggle button. The fieldset will be expanded when the checkbox is checked and collapsed when it is unchecked. The checkbox will also be included in the form submit parameters using the checkboxName as its parameter name."